# Login to site with Windows Phone WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to login to a site using Windows Phone `WebBrowser`.

```
<form id="loginform" method="post" action="viaJavascript" onsubmit="formSubmit(); return false;">       
    <h2>Password</h2>

    <p>
       <input type="hidden" name="user" maxlength="8" />
       <input type="password" name="pwd" maxlength="29" />
       <input type="hidden" name="from" value="/adminweb/jsp/timetables/timetablesController.jsp" />
       <input type="hidden" name="query" value="" />                     
    </p>
</form>
```

This is the JavaScript function:

```
function formSubmit(){
    var loginform1 = document.getElementById('loginform1');
    var loginform = document.getElementById('loginform');
    loginform.user.value = loginform1.user.value;
    loginform.action = "/adminweb/servlet/login";
    loginform.submit();
}
```

I did this successfully in a `Windows.Form` using:

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("user").SetAttribute("value", Store_Login.Get_Username());
```

I know how to invoke the `OnSubmit()` using `InvokeScript`, but how do I set the values `user` and `pwd`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the `eval` function using `InvokeScript`. Use this to execute JavaScript code which sets username and password:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('name').value = 'username';");
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('pwd').value = 'password';");
```

One possible caveat is that some sites block the execution of `eval`. But it sounds like you are targeting a specific site. Try if it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, your code got me going in the right direction `webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('loginform1').user.value = 'username';");`  This code worked for me

Comment: I need to get the value from this `<input type="button" name="Current week" value="Current week" onclick="javascript:void+displayTimetable('14')" />`  The '14' changes each week

Comment: See my answer on your other question ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261974/get-attribute-value-from-html-element-in-webbrowser/8263184#8263184