# Get attribute value from HTML element in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-7

I need the number in brackets, in this case "14" so that I can send it to a JavaScript function on the page to submit or alternatively is there a way to 'click' the button "Current week"?

```
<form id="timetablesForm" action="timetablesController.jsp" method="post">
    <p>
        <input type="button" name="Current week" value="Current week" onclick="javascript:void+displayTimetable('14')" />
        <input type="button" name="Next week" value="Next week" onclick="javascript:void+displayTimetable('15')" />
        <input type="button" name="Current semester" value="Semester 1" onclick="javascript:void displayTimetable('7;8;9;10;11;12;13;14;15;16;17;21')" />
    </p>

function displayTimetable(selectdweeks)
```

I'm working in Windows Phone so the `WebBrowser.Document` isn't available. I've used the script below to set a value in a different form:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('loginform1').user.value = 'username';");
```

How do I **get** a value from the HTML page? What other function can I call with `InvokeScript`? Appreciate it if you can point me at a list of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
webBrowser1.SaveToString()
```

Then parse the HTML to get the bit I want

Answer (score 1):

The following code extracts the "14" from your first input "Current week":

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // first define a new function which returns the content of "onclick" as string
    webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "this.newfunc_getmyvalue = function() { return document.getElementById('Current week').attributes.getNamedItem('onclick').value; }");
    // now invoke the function and save the result (which will be "javascript:void+displayTimetable('14')")
    string onclickstring = (string)webBrowser1.InvokeScript("newfunc_getmyvalue");
    // now split the string at the single quotes (you might have to adapt this parsing logic to whatever string you expect; this is just a simple approach)
    string[] substrings = Regex.Split(onclickstring, "'");
    // this shows a messagebox saying "14"
    MessageBox.Show(substrings[1]);
}
```

A little background:

Initially I thought that returning a value should be as easy as:

```
// ATTENTION: THIS DOESN'T WORK
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "return 'hello';");
```

But this always throws a `SystemException` ("An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80020101.") This is the reason why the code above first defines a JavaScript function which returns the desired value. Then we call this function and the result is returned successfully.

Comment: The second cast string line keeps throwing that same exception "Error: 80020101." Is it possible to "click" the button "Current week" with this method? I either need 14 or to click it. Many thanks

Comment: Strange. For me it works. Are you running Mango? Try `webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('Current week').click()");` for clicking.

Comment: app targets WP OS 7.1, and that code also throws a systemexception for me :(

Comment: But the first `InvokeScript` line works? So `IsScriptEnabled` is `True` for the WebBrowser? Do you have a live sample of the web page somewhere? I just had your HTML snippet and used NavigateToString() to load it. Maybe that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you for all your effort, really appreciate it, i think I'm just going to have to using SaveToString, and parse everything so just the number is left, ugly way but simple :P

Comment: Yeah, SaveToString() worked, two string split operations then can invokeScript with one string as parameter, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing just that, getting the value?

```
Object val = webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('loginform1').user.value;");
```

Comment: have tried many variations of `Object val = webBrowser1.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('timetablesForm').'Current week'.onclick.value;");` but all throw a SystemException